# Dynamic structure to byte array conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, buffer

I am developing a C# application which reads the contents of a binary file and displays the same in a datagrid view. The format of the data is something like this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class sProtParElement
{
    public ushort wNameIndex; 
    public eDataTypeTag eDataType; //eDataTypeTag is an enum
    public ushort wLen;
    public Data_Variant_tag Vt_Var; //Data_Variant_tag is a struct
}
```

where,

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Data_Variant_tag
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]public byte yVal;
    [FieldOffset(0)]public sbyte cVal;
    [FieldOffset(0)]public ushort wVal;
    [FieldOffset(0)]public short iVal;
    [FieldOffset(0)]public uint xVal;
    [FieldOffset(0)]public int lVal;
    [FieldOffset(0)]public IntPtr pcVal;
}
```

Now, the user can make changes to the data from the datagrid view and save the updated data in a buffer so that it can be written back to the file again.

The issue I face is the because of the varying data type. When I want to write the contents back to a byte array, I simple cannot use a fixed struct size because of the varying data type size I encounter.

Can someone tell me how do I create a dynamic buffer and write only the required data size in the byte buffer ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asx0thw2.aspx) class to convert structures with *Explicit* and *Sequential* layouts to byte arrays.

```
var element = new sProtParElement()
{
    wLen = 1,
    wNameIndex = 2,
    Vt_Var = new Data_Variant_tag { lVal = 3 }
};

var size = Marshal.SizeOf(element);
var buffer = new byte[size];
IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
try
{
    ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(element, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, buffer, 0, size);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate new buffer. All data before modified structure must be copied as it is. All data after the modified buffer must be shifted. You can use `System.Buffer` class for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I used the generics combined with Lambda expressions to arrive at my solution.

Since the members in the structure are of different sizes based on the data type, I created a list of byte arrays which already holds all the elements of the datagrid view

Now every time, the user makes a change in the data grid view, I create a temporary buffer and just overwrite the original buffer contents e.g.

```
             byte[] modifiedArray = 
             GenerateByteArrayFromPPDataList(e.RowIndex,newPPDataList[e.RowIndex].eDataType); 

      listofArrays[e.RowIndex] = modifiedArray; //listofArrays[e.RowIndex] -> byte array at index position e.RowIndex
```

Then I use lambda expression to vectorize this list. I used the example from stackoverflow to do this.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converst the list of byte arrays which contains the 
    /// protocol paramters into a single byte array
    /// </summary>
    private void VectorizeProtParList()
    {
        if (listofArrays != null && listofArrays.Count > 0)
        {
            var flattenedList =
                listofArrays.SelectMany(bytes => bytes);

            savedPPDataArray = flattenedList.ToArray();

            MessageBox.Show("New Protocol parameter data saved", "Save Data",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PP Data list seems to have no data", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

The savedPPDataArray is my final byte buffer which I write back to the file.

Cheers,
Harish